# Vertigo (mutation testing for Solidity) - Command not found on Mac OS

Tags: testing, blockchain, solidity, mutation-testing

I am on a Mac and want to install and use Vertigo (software tool for mutation testing Solidity smart contracts).

I follow the installation instructions here: https://pypi.org/project/eth-vertigo/

And install Vertigo with:

```bash
> pip3 install eth-vertigo
```

Then, I run:

```bash
> vertigo
zsh: command not found: vertigo
```

There seems to be a missing step in the instructions (in my case)!

Answer (score 1):

When you install Vertigo with `pip3` it tells you the path, e.g.:

```bash
/some/path/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/
```

Look in the output, on the command line, from the installation.

Then, the vertigo binary file (which we thought would execute natively) is located here:

```bash
/some/path/.local/bin/vertigo
```

So, to make this work, please add the `bin/` path to your `PATH` variable like so:

```bash
> export PATH="${PATH}:/some/path/.local/bin/"
```

Now it should work:

```bash
> vertigo
Usage: vertigo [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

  Mutation testing framework for smart contracts

Options:
  --help  Show this message and exit.

Commands:
  run  Performs a core test campaign
```

Perhaps this is related to it not installing properly in virtual environments.